# Pdf generated from html using jsPdf displaying black in nodemailer attachment

Tags: next.js, jspdf, nodemailer, next.js13

I'm trying to generate pdf from html using jsPdf and attach the same on nodemailer.

The pdf document will be generated, but will be black when opened from the mail.

Am using nextjs, my code is as follows:

```
import { mailOptions, transporter } from "@/configs/nodemailer";
import generateEmailContent from "@/lib/contents/createEmailContents";
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';


const pdf = new jsPDF({
  orientation: "portrait", 
  unit: "cm", 
  format: "a4", 
});


const createPDF = async () => {
  pdf.html(`<div id="contentToPrint"><h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1></div>`)

  const pdfOutput = pdf.output("datauristring");

  return pdfOutput;
};



export const POST = async (request) => {

    if (request.method === "POST") {
        let pdfOutput = await createPDF();
    try {
          await transporter.sendMail({
            ...mailOptions,
            ...generateEmailContent(),
            attachments: [{ path: pdfOutput }],
          });
  
        return new Response("SUCCESS", { status: 201 })
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return new Response("Failed to create a new prompt", { status: 500 });
      }
    }
    return new Response("Failed to create a new prompt", { status: 500 });

}
```

Please, I need someone to help
Thanks